# Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova add a Jar from 3party

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I'm using Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova to develop hybird app,mainly Jquery mobile. And now I'd like to consume a thrid party jar file.
  Is it possible Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova can add a Jar file into my project ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen devs use the `lib` folder, in the built application, as a destination for .jar files. This post looks helpful: [How to include jar files in phonegap android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31341904/how-to-include-jar-files-in-phonegap-android-application)

Quoting the answer:

> `<source-file src="libs/mylib.jar" target-dir="libs" />`
>
> "libs" is the default folder for storing .jar files so your lib will
>   be linked.
>
> Take a look at an existing plugin using an external lib.
>
> An example
>   (https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-phonegap-3.0-plugin)